# I'm having trouble to sort my results database

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am Brazilian and I am using google translate , I apologize for any English errors.

I have to specify a search result that records the month and year of an event as well.

```
SELECT fornecedores.*
    ,controle_fornecedores.*
    ,datas_cont_fornecedor.*
FROM controle_fornecedores
INNER JOIN fornecedores 
        ON controle_fornecedores.idFornecedor = fornecedores.id
INNER JOIN datas_cont_fornecedor 
        ON controle_fornecedores.id = datas_cont_fornecedor.idContForn
WHERE (
        MONTH(controle_fornecedores.compra) = '02'
        AND YEAR(controle_fornecedores.compra) = '2013'
        )
ORDER BY controle_fornecedores.danfe
    ,fornecedores.apelido ASC
    ,controle_fornecedores.compra
    ,datas_cont_fornecedor.vencimento ASC
```

I'm pulling other results there, but that can be ignored. My problem is when it returns me the correct day and month, the date is disorganized. I would like to organize it in ascending order. How would I do so in this case?

For better understanding, this result is generated xls (excel) and in the case would be the following:

[image]

see that the date is out of order I would put the same growing 01,02,03 and so on.

however in my select whether you realize I'm already asking to leave ASC but does not work.

Comment: You're sorting by Apelido before Compra.  Maybe reverse the order of the first two in `ORDER BY`?  Of course then your Italia will be mixed with your Geio & Cia etc...

Comment: Hello friend thanks for replying,
then this code I use the same for various searches it is an order only thing I change is in the same condition 'WHERE' but in my case I do not know what I do my search works correctly my only problem is to sort these dates growing ...

Comment: replace your `ORDER BY` with: `ORDER BY controle_fornecedores.danfe,controle_fornecedores.compra, fornecedores.apelido ASC, datas_cont_fornecedor.vencimento ASC`  If the **order** is incorrect it stands to reason **`ORDER BY`** is responsible.

Comment: sorry buddy, I did not understand what you mean

Comment: good day, then the whole point is that I need to sort more than one column